Given two rectangular matrices and they yield the same results when they are multiplied by their own transposes. What can we say about them?
Suppose we have $MM^T = NN^T$, where $M$ and $N$ are both $n$ by $d$ matrices. Assume that $n$ is (much) larger than $d$, are there anything we could conclude about $M$ and $N$, aside from that $N$ could be a permutation of $M$?
In another word, if given a $n$ by $d$ dimension matrix $M$ and $MM^T = X$, can we efficiently find a matrix $N$ such that $N$ has the same dimension as $M$ and also $NN^T = X$ (where $N$ can't be a permutation of $M$'s columns)?

You say "In another word", but the two questions of what you know about solutions, and how you can generate solutions, seem to be different.

It's a standard result that the exact relationship between $M$ and $N$ is that they're related by a real unitary (sometimes called real orthogonal) matrix. That is, there's a real $d \times d$ unitary matrix $U$ such that $M = NU$. When $U$ is a permutation matrix, you get the permutation fact that you noted. When $U$ is unitary but not a permutation, you get something else (which seems to be what you want).
